# Is checking for a BOOL's value more efficient than just updating it?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, performance

I have a quick efficiency question.

Suppose I have a Boolean that gets set to YES very often (when the player is on the ground).

Would it be more efficient to just check for the BOOL's value, i.e.

`if (!character.isOnGround) character.isOnGround = YES;`

Or would it be more efficient to just set the value to YES, i.e.

`character.isOnGround = YES`

Basically, the question is this. Is an if statement faster than an assignment?

Comment: No. Just set the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (!character.isOnGround) character.isOnGround = YES;
```

Will need:

- Read of variable
- Condition Check
- Branching
- Write of variable

Though the optimizing compiler may just collapse into last statement.